# React-spring: animate div containing an animated image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-spring

I'm trying to use `react-spring` to animate a `div` and an image inside this `div`, code below. So far, the `dangleProps` is working properly: the image is animated, however, the div isn't: `hoveredProps` isn't working for some reason, trying to figure it out:

#### Icon.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useSpring, animated } from "react-spring";

export const Icon = ({ showPage, imageSource, altText, index }) => {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

  const dangleProps = useSpring({
    transform: showPage ? "rotateZ(0deg)" : "rotateZ(180deg)",
    transformOrigin: "top",
    from: { transform: "rotateZ(180deg)" },
    config: { mass: 1, tension: 210 - index * 50, friction: 5 },
  });

  const hoveredProps = useSpring({
    transform: isHovered ? "rotateZ(320deg)" : "rotateZ(0)",
    from: { transform: "rotateZ(0)" },
    config: { mass: 1, tension: 210, friction: 5 },
  });

  return (
    <animated.div
      className="contact-icon"
      onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
      style={hoveredProps}
    >
      <animated.img src={imageSource} alt={altText} style={dangleProps} />
    </animated.div>
  );
};
```

---

```css
section.contact {
  background-color: rgba(160, 210, 140, 0.3);
  margin: 0;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.contact-icon {
  margin: 0 calc(1vw + 10px);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.contact-icon img {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Note: `section.contact` wraps several `<Icon />`s

Comment: can you add your css, please

Comment: Added css, cheers~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example was hard to reproduce. Finally I managed.

The problem is, that you did not specify the unit for the `roteteZ`. If you add the deg to all of the occurance it will work.

```
  const hoveredProps = useSpring({
    transform: isHovered ? "rotateZ(320deg)" : "rotateZ(0deg)",
    from: { transform: "rotateZ(0deg)" },
    config: { mass: 1, tension: 210, friction: 5 },
  });
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-monad-tb41s

Comment: OMG! I can not believe I've missed it. Thank you SOOOOO MUCH!!!!! and sorry for the trouble